# Converting Date in JavaScript is not working in Firefox

Tags: javascript, date, datetime, firefox

```
// Date library for DateTime comparisons and checkingifa date is in-between arange of 2 dates!
// Source: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/497790
var dates = {

  // Format a Date string or object as "9/17/2015 8:15 pm"
  // var date can be;
  // - Date String = creates date object with DateTime in the string
  // - String value of "now" = creates date object with current DateTime
  // - Date Object = uses the Date object passed in
  // - null/no value = creates date object with current DateTime
  formatDate: function(date) {
      if (typeof(date) == "undefined") {
          date = new Date();
      } else if (typeof(date) == "string") {
          if (date == 'now') {
              date = new Date();
          } else {
              var date_string = date;
              date = new Date(date_string);
          }
      }

      var hours = date.getHours();
      var minutes = date.getMinutes();
      var ampm = hours >= 12 ? 'pm' : 'am';
      hours = hours % 12;
      hours = hours ? hours : 12; // the hour '0' should be '12'
      minutes = minutes < 10 ? '0' + minutes : minutes;
      var strTime = hours + ':' + minutes + ' ' + ampm;
      return date.getMonth() + 1 + "/" + date.getDate() + "/" + date.getFullYear() + " " + strTime;
  },
};
```

Format Date in JavaScript...

```
console.log(dates.formatDate('2014-06-17 00:00:00'));
```

Returns `NaN/NaN/NaN 12:NaN am` in FIrefox and `6/17/2014 12:00 am` in Chrome

Passing in a Date without a time works fine in Firefox

```
console.log(dates.formatDate('2014-06-17'));
```

Returns `6/16/2014 8:00 pm` in FIrefox

---

I would like to be able to pass in a Date with a time or witohut a time and have it work in FIrefox and Chrome

Comment: firefox expects date in this format `2014-06-17T00:00:00`. Check [Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date)  for valid date formats in firefox. and this format behaves differently in chrome tested now , it add timezone for time part

Comment: @JSantosh I was trying to make this function allow a JS Date object, a date string, or the string text `now` and if empty then create Date for now.  SO it would be really flexible.  Do you know if there is a way to still do that with FIrefox?

Comment: currently your issue is with firefox , so detect the browser using `if ($.browser.mozilla) { ... ` and use @Amit answer to get date in firefox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `new Date(date_string)` constructor supports the same date formats supported by [`Date.parse()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse), namely RFC2822 and ISO 8601. Additional support is optional, but not mandatory.

Your string is in neither of the supported formats, and is unrecognized by Firefox. It is also "safe" to assume it won't be supported by other JavaScript engines.

On the other hand, if you specifically expect this format, you can easily convert it to ISO 8601:

```js
alert(new Date('2014-06-17 00:00:00'.replace(' ', 'T')))
```

Comment: Thanks, learning something new daily this is my first time looking at all my Date code in FIrefox, was supprised when it all broke!

Comment: Most of my Date strings come from a MySQL DateTime field

Comment: BTW, dates in JS are a sore point. You might want to have a look at [Moment.JS](http://momentjs.com/) for a library that soothes the pain :-)

Comment: I was against using moment.js due to it's bulk size but now I see these sort of issues might make it worth it!